# CosmosDB - list in aggregate query response

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have following document structure:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "aId": "2",
 "bId": "3",

  ....
},
{ "id":"2",
  "aId": "2",
  "bId": "4"
}
```

How do i return for that JSON that has aId that has list of all bIds of the same aId, and as additional field: count of such bIds? So for example above and condtion: "WHERE aId="2" response would be:

```
{ 
"aId": "2",
"bIds" : ["4","3"],
"bIds count" : 2

}
```

Assuming i only pass one aId as parameter.

I tried something like:

```
select 
   (select 'something') as aId,
   (select distinct value c.bId from c where c.aId='something') as bIds
from TableName c
```

But for love of me i cant figure out how to get that list + its count + hardcoded aId in single JSON response (single row)

For example this query:

```
select 
(select distinct value 'someId') as aId, 
(select distinct value c.bId) as bIds
from c where c.aId='someId'
```

will return

```
{ { 'aId': 'someId', 'bIds':'2'},{'aId':'someId','bIds':'4'}}
```

while what i acutally want is

```
{ {'aId':''someId', 'bIds':['2','4']}}
```

Here is query that is closest to what i want:

```
select 
 c.aId as aId, 
 count(c2) as bIdCount,
 array(select distinct value c2.bId from c2)
 from c join (select c.bId from c) as c2
 where c.aId = 'SOME_ID'
```

Only thing line with array make this query fail if i delete this line it works (correctly returns id and count in one row). But i need to select content of this list also, and i ma lost why its not working, example is almost copypasted from "How to perform array projection Cosmos Db"
https://azurelessons.com/array-in-cosmos-db/#How_to_perform_array_projection_Azure_Cosmos_DB

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you'd return an array of `bId`:

```sql
SELECT  distinct value c.bId
FROM c
where c.aId = "2"
```

This yields:

```json
[
   "3",
   "4"
]
```

Removing the `value` keyword:

```sql
SELECT  distinct c.bId
FROM c
where c.aId = "2"
```

yields:

```json
[
   { "bId" : "3" },
   { "bId" : "4" }
]
```

From either of these, you can count the number of array elements returned. If your payload must include count and `aId`, you'll need to add those to your JSON output.

Comment: I know how to count them and i know and i know how to return list. My problem with similiar queries is that i get one row for every unique id so in this case 2 rows, Instead of that i want 1 row (because i pass only one aId) where one of the field is list of bIds. According to your example this should work:

Comment: select distinct 'someId', distinct value c.bId from c where c.aId='someId' But this is not even valid query

Comment: I don't understand your comment - my first query returns a single array with all distinct IDs, not multiple "rows". I included the 2nd example as an alternative. You would need to handle such a return value accordingly.

Comment: For example this query: "select (select distinct value 'someId'), (select distinct value c.bId)  from c where c.aId='someId' " will return { { 'aId': 'someId', 'bId':'2'},{'aId':'someId','bId':'4'}} while what i acutally want is { {'aId':''someId', 'bIds':['2','4']}}.

Comment: So you suggest its impossible to get such return in single query? @David Makogon Or both 'someId', listofBids and its count in single query that has some subqueries?

Comment: fyi you really need to edit your question at this point. It's very difficult to read unformatted code/queries in comments.

Comment: Ok @David Makogon, i edited last sentence which may caused confusion but i included example response i want when i first created question, please check it out