# CosmosDB: How can I return a query as a list of strings only?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Ex, suppose I have:

```
[
    {
      "obj1": {
        "$t": 2,
        "$v": "valueA"
      },
      "obj2": {
        "$t": 2,
        "$v": "valueB"
      }
]
```

If I do something like SELECT Resources.obj2["$v"], it returns something like

```
   [
        {
          "$v": "valueB"
        }
   ]
```

How do I get it to return JUST the string value as an array? like:

```
   {
        
      "valueB"
        
   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: there should be json function for that

Comment: Try using the `value` keyword - I have examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178699/2721090) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73683798/272109)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use

```
SELECT value Resources.obj2["$v"]
FROM c
```